# I want to pass some argument get from intent to doBackground

Tags: android

This is my code,it gets detail from previous activity:it get two values as location and bloodGroup and SearchDonor will get it and process it.

```
Intent intent =getIntent();

location = intent.getStringExtra("location");

 bloodgroup = intent.getStringExtra("bloodgroup");
```

so iget an when i write it in doBackGround process,i want to add above code in following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchDonor extends ListActivity {
private Context context;
private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/bl/getDonor.php";

private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
private static final String TAG_MIDDLENAME = "MiddleName";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "LastName";

private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
private static final String TAG_CELLPHONE = "CellPhone";
private static final String TAG_DONORS = "donors";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DONORID = "Donor_ID";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String TAG_BLOODGROUP = "bloodgroup";



JSONArray donors = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView lv ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_donor);





    new ProgressTask(SearchDonor.this).execute();






}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DonorDetails.class);

    String did=( (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.donorId)).getText().toString();
    String Name=( (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.vehicleType)).getText().toString();
    String Address=( (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.vehicleColor)).getText().toString();
    String cellphone=( (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fuel)).getText().toString();

    intent.putExtra("did", did);
    intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
    intent.putExtra("Address", Address);
    intent.putExtra("cellPhone", cellphone);

    startActivity(intent);

}



private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private ListActivity activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }



        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DONORID,TAG_FIRSTNAME , TAG_ADDRESS,
                        TAG_CELLPHONE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.donorId,R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
         lv = getListView();





    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();





        List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LOCATION,location));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_BLOODGROUP,bloodgroup));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET",params);

        // getting JSON string from URL
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                donors = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DONORS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < donors.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = donors.getJSONObject(i);

                    String donoID = c.getString(TAG_DONORID);

                String firstName = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME );
                String middleName = c.getString(TAG_MIDDLENAME );
                String lastName = c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME );
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS );
                String cellPhone = c.getString(TAG_CELLPHONE );

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_DONORID, donoID);

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, firstName);
                map.put(TAG_MIDDLENAME, middleName);
                map.put(TAG_LASTNAME ,lastName);
                map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                map.put(TAG_CELLPHONE, cellPhone);
                jsonlist.add(map);
                }
                }

            else{
                String message ="No Donor Found";
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, message);
                map.put(TAG_MIDDLENAME, "");
                map.put(TAG_LASTNAME ,"");
                map.put(TAG_ADDRESS,"");
                map.put(TAG_CELLPHONE, "");
                jsonlist.add(map);
            }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return null;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried this code? It's not working? Your `ProgressTask` is a inner class of `SearchDonor`, so it have access to the `getIntent` method.

Comment: this work perfectly.if i use manual string like, location = "xxx" BloodGroup ="A +ve".but where to use getIntent method

Comment: @Prathm Where are you setting the adapter to ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both values (comma separated or as array) in execute() method, and these values will be available in doInBackground() method.

**Code:**

```
// Calling AsyncTask in onCreate()
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_donor);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i!=null) {
         location = intent.getStringExtra("location");
         bloodgroup = intent.getStringExtra("bloodgroup");

         new ProgressTask(SearchDonor.this).execute(location,bloodgroup);

     } 
}



private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String...params) 
{

      // Getting values from params
      String location = params[0];
      String bloodGroup= params[1];
      ....
}
```

I did not run the code but it will give you the idea for doing. If you get any error post here.